# Как перенаправить исходящий запрос?

Tags: сеть

Есть прога, которая делает запрос на определенный url 
(пусть это будет **example.com/api/query.php**) и передает некие параметры через POST. Как я могу перенаправить весь исходящий трафик с этого пути на, к примеру **second-example.com/second-api/index.php**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать как то так:

1. Поднять локально nginx, и сделать редирект. 
   Если мне не изменяет память, то приблизительно так:

```
upstream right_example_com
{
  server ip_address_of_example_com:80;
}
server
{
  listen localhost:80;
  server_name example.com;
  location ~ /api/query.php(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(/api/query.php)(.*)$   http://second-example.com/second-api/index.php$2 permanent;
  } 
  location /
  {
    proxy_pass         http://right_example_com;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

2. В /etc/hosts внести запись `127.0.0.1 localhost example.com`